# Isolate scope in Directive with TypeScript and Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, definitelytyped

I am stuck on an issue when trying to create a new angular directive using TypeScript. The issue only happens if I am planning to use the isolate scope in the directive. Following is what I am doing:

```
module Foo.Layout {
    "use strict";
    class SidebarDirective implements ng.IDirective {

        templateUrl = "/layout/sidebar/sidebar.html";
        restrict = "E";
        controller = SidebarController;
        scope = {
            align: "@"
        }

        static factory() {
            var instance = () => {
                return new SidebarDirective();
            }
            return instance;
        }       
    }
    angular.module("app.layout").directive("fooSidebar", SidebarDirective.factory());
}
```

The issue only happens when adding the `scope = {...}` statement else it compiles fine. Below goes the error.

> Error TS2420  Class 'SidebarDirective' incorrectly implements interface
>   'IDirective'.   Types of property 'scope' are incompatible.
>   Type '{ orientation: string; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean | { [boundProperty: string]: string; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type '{ orientation: string; }'

And yes in my typings `ng.IDirective` has the scope property of type `scope?: boolean | {[boundProperty: string]: string};`

What is the ideal way to create an isolate scope in my directive? (I am using the angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped version 6.5.5)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
scope = {
            align: "="
        }
```

Comment: Can you post also how you use it?